# API requests using python

Tags: python, api, curl, python-requests

I am trying to do a request using python. The API uses:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{ \ 
   "$class": "org.acme.model.sensor", \ 
   "sensorId": "1", \ 
   "type": "Temperature", \ 
   "value": "10", \ 
   "timestamp": 1234123 \ 
 }' 'http://localhost:3000/api/sensor'
```

to create a new sensor. I am trying to do it with python and I have created the proof of concept:

```
data = {
    "$class": "org.acme.model.sensor",
    "sensorId": "",  #change in the loop with i
    "type": "Temperature",
    "value": "10",
    "timestamp": 382453824
}

header = {
    "Content-Type" : "application/json",
    "Accept":"application/json"
}

url = "http://localhost:3000/api/sensor"
for i in range(2):
    data["sensorId"]=str(i+1)
    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header)

    #Now I modify the data
    data["Temperature"]="50"
    response = requests.put(url, data=data, headers=header)
```

Now, for erasing:

```
for i in range(2):
    url="http://localhost:3000/api/sensor/"+str(i+1)
    response = requests.delete(url)
```

With curl, it works properly but no with the python code. It fails even creating the object.

Comment: I'm really not good with this but I recently had an issue where I had to use `json=data` in the POST rather than `data=data`.

Comment: How does it fail? what's the Traceback?

Comment: Using json It works, but I am unable to change the temperature to 50

Comment: "is not working" is not a useful description of your problem. Please explain what result you get (including the exact error message and full traceback if you have an exception).

Comment: Itś solved, I got an 404 error, I was because of the server sintaxis to make "put" thanks to everyone

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests
import json

header = {
"Content-Type" : "application/json",
"Accept":"application/json"
}
```

You need to convert your dictionary into a proper format using `json.dumps` and need to use `request.post` instead of `delete`

```
request_url = 'YOUR_END_POINT'
data = json.dumps(data)
response = requests.post(url=request_url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

I think that should solve it.